nodemailer with microsoft live mail failed with Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled
I use nodemailer to send mail with microsoft email account xxx@live.cn. I have enabled MFA in my microsoft acccount and created application password to use it in nodemailer.
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const ENV = process.env;
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
        user: ENV.SENDER_USER,
        pass: ENV.SENDER_PASS,
    },
});

It had worked ok until three day ago. I found the error Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. [BN9PR03CA0655.namprd03.prod.outlook.com 2024-09-20T00:31:14.186Z 08DCD82D4D9A014B] emitted.
Does nodemailer can not used for micorsoft email now?

I have the same problem

Microsoft shut down basic authentication (with only username/password) on September 16.
